# Apollo-Kotlin: After creating schema.graphql android studio is showing Unsupported token `!` error

Tags: android, graphql, apollo-kotlin

Steps that I made so far.

- Downloaded an install the graphql plugin to execute the queries internally. [image: plugin for graphql from plugin -> marketplace]
- Created this config file for executing local queries for the expected behavior. [image: Ref]
- Which is working fine with performing general query. But with this config I am getting following error while building project and run it on a device. [image: getting error like this]

  ```
   Failed to parse GraphQL file E:\...\src\main\graphql\schema.graphql (9:13) Unsupported token `!`
  ```

FYI, I have already gone through [this ticket](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-kotlin/issues/2718) from apollo-kotlin github page. Doesn't resolve my problem or I don't understand the solution there.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: version 2.5.6 @mbonnin
When I deleted the `E:\...\src\main\graphql\schema.graphql` file and it's working fine now! I don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now,
By deleting the `E:\...\src\main\graphql\schema.graphql` file, the project builds and runs just fine.

If anyone has more idea on this, let me know and I will update if I find anything else as well. Thanks

Comment: Your shcema must have `.graphqls` as an extension. Else it will be parsed as a query and trigger such errors.